Postgresql patroni cluster switchover error
root@testpatroni1:~# patronictl switchover --master test_patroni1 --candidate  test_patroni2

Error: Can not find suitable configuration of distributed configuration store
Available implementations: etcd, etcd3, kubernetes

I get this error when I do a switchover in Patroni. What could be the reason?
the current situation

Patroni was getting an error with the following command because the configuration file was not in the default location.
If it is written this way, the Leader will change;
patronictl -c /to/path/patroni.yml switchover --master test_patroni1 --candidate test_patroni2
